# Save and print PDF from a FDF file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, fdf

I have the below macro that fills the data from excel to a PDF. I would like to enhance the code to save the PDF and also print it. The name for the file is located in cell A5. The current code saves the FDF to my directory. Below is the code used and is taken from the following link: http://blog.excelhero.com/2010/04/14/excel_acrobat_pdf_form_filler/:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Private Const SW_NORMAL = 1
Public Const PDF_FILE = "f8655.pdf"


Public Sub MakeFDF()

    Dim sFileHeader As String
    Dim sFileFooter As String
    Dim sFileFields As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim lngFileNum As Long
    Dim vClient As Variant
    
    
    ' Builds string for contents of FDF file and then writes file to workbook folder.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    sFileHeader = "%FDF-1.2" & vbCrLf & _
                  "%âãÏÓ" & vbCrLf & _
                  "1 0 obj<</FDF<</F(" & PDF_FILE & ")/Fields 2 0 R>>>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "endobj" & vbCrLf & _
                  "2 0 obj[" & vbCrLf
                  
    sFileFooter = "]" & vbCrLf & _
                  "endobj" & vbCrLf & _
                  "trailer" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</Root 1 0 R>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "%%EO"
    

    sFileFields = "<</T(f1_01(0))/V(---NAME---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_02(0))/V(---EIN_LEFT---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_03(0))/V(---EIN_RIGHT---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_06(0))/V(---OIN---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_04(0))/V(---TRADE_NAME---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                   "<</T(c1_1(0))/V(---SEASONAL---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_05(0))/V(---STREET_ADDRESS---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_07(0))/V(---CITY_STATE_ZIP---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_08(0))/V(---CONTACT---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_09(0))/V(---PHONE_LEFT---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_10(0))/V(---PHONE_RIGHT---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_11(0))/V(---FAX_LEFT---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(f1_12(0))/V(---FAX_RIGHT---)>>" & vbCrLf
    
    
    vClient = Range(Selection.Row & ":" & Selection.Row)
    
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---NAME---", vClient(1, 2))
    If Len(vClient(1, 3)) > 3 Then
        sTmp = Replace(vClient(1, 3), "-", "")
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---EIN_LEFT---", Left$(sTmp, 2))
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---EIN_RIGHT---", Mid$(sTmp, 3))
    Else
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---EIN_LEFT---", vbNullString)
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---EIN_RIGHT---", vbNullString)
    End If
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---OIN---", vClient(1, 4))
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---TRADE_NAME---", vClient(1, 5))
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---SEASONAL---", vClient(1, 6))
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---STREET_ADDRESS---", vClient(1, 7))
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---CITY_STATE_ZIP---", vClient(1, 8))
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---CONTACT---", vClient(1, 9))
    If Len(vClient(1, 10)) = 10 Then
        sTmp = Replace(vClient(1, 10), "-", "")
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---PHONE_LEFT---", Left$(sTmp, 3))
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---PHONE_RIGHT---", Mid$(sTmp, 4, 3) & "-" & Mid$(sTmp, 7))
    Else
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---PHONE_LEFT---", vbNullString)
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---PHONE_RIGHT---", vbNullString)
    End If
    If Len(vClient(1, 11)) = 10 Then
        sTmp = Replace(vClient(1, 11), "-", "")
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---FAX_LEFT---", Left$(sTmp, 3))
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---FAX_RIGHT---", Mid$(sTmp, 4, 3) & "-" & Mid$(sTmp, 7))
    Else
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---FAX_LEFT---", vbNullString)
        sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---FAX_RIGHT---", vbNullString)
    End If

    sTmp = sFileHeader & sFileFields & sFileFooter
    
    
    ' Write FDF file to disk
    If Len(vClient(1, 1)) Then sFileName = vClient(1, 1) Else sFileName = "FDF_DEMO"
    sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName & ".fdf"
    lngFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Output As lngFileNum
    Print #lngFileNum, sTmp
    Close #lngFileNum
    DoEvents
    
    ' Open FDF file as PDF
    ShellExecute vbNull, "open", sFileName, vbNull, vbNull, SW_NORMAL
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "MakeFDF Error: " + Str(Err.Number) + " " + Err.Description + " " + Err.Source

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit 

Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _ 
ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
ByVal lpOperation As String, _ 
ByVal lpFile As String, _ 
ByVal lpParameters As String, _ 
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _ 
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _ 
As Long 

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String) 
    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)  
End Sub 

Sub Test() 
    PrintFile ("C:\Test.pdf") 
End Sub
```

Add this code as it is and just make the call to PrintFile under your desired location and pass your file path in your case sFileName so final call would be :
PrintFile sFileName

Comment: Hi Mick Just add it as per your choice. I mean on a button or any other interface from which you want to get this job done.